# How to set multiple scope in OAuth2Parameters?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to set multiple scope in OAuth2Parameters. How can I set multiple scopes?
Here is my code.

```
//Scope for Calendar and Contact Group
    string[] scopes = new string[] {Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly, "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/"};

    OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
    parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
    parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
    parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;          
    parameters.Scope=scopes[0];         //here parameters.Scope has String type. I can only set only 1 scope.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to send multiple scopes with parameters, then add multiple `Scope` into one string with `space` as a delimiter.

```
var ScopeString = @"myscope/as/1 myscope/as/2" ;
```

Then set this string to `parameter.Scope` property.

```
 parameters.Scope= ScopeString;
```

This works for any generic `OAuth` Process, verify it though.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Scopes is just a string array.  Just add more separate them with a comma.

```
/// <summary>
        /// The Google APIs Client Library for .net uses the client_secrets.json file format for storing the client_id, client_secret, and other OAuth 2.0 parameters.
        /// The client_secrets.json file format is a JSON formatted file containing the client ID, client secret, and other OAuth 2.0 parameters.
        ///      
        /// This file can be obtained from Google Developers console:   https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
        /// <param name="userName">The user to authorize.</param>
        /// <returns>a valid CalendarService</returns>
        public static CalendarService AuthenticateOauth(string clientSecretJson, string userName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new Exception("userName is required for datastore.");

            if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
                throw new Exception("Cant find Client Secret Json file.");

            string[] scopes = new string[] {  CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,            // Manage your calendars
                                             CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly, // View your calendars
                                             "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/",
                                             "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/"};                  

         try
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/Calendar");

                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        scopes,
                        userName,
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }

                // Create Calendar API service.
                var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "Calendar Authentication Sample",
                    });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                throw ex;

            }
        }
```

**TOP Tip:**  "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/"  are both gdata apis are are not going to work with the current version of the .net client library which only supports discovery APIs.   That being said there is no reason you cant use it for authentication to the contacts API you just wont be able to access the contacts api using this client library you will have to use the gdata client library.